# Gradle - Error Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0]

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to open existing android project in android studio and it gradle cannot build the app without the error

Error android studio keeps on throwing

```
Error:(74, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments 
[com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0] on object of type 
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

My Code in build.gradle Which can help to understand my issue
My dependencies

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

// google & support
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:palette-v7:$supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:$supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportVersion"
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.0.4'

// utils
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0'
implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.7'
implementation 'com.github.Commit451:bypasses:1.0.4'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.0'
implementation 'com.drewnoakes:metadata-extractor:2.9.1'
implementation "com.orhanobut:hawk:2.0.1"

}
```

Please help to solve the issue

Comment: Are you using Android Studio 3.0?

Comment: I am new to android. But Yes, I updated to 3.0 as previous error was complaining about it.

Comment: Nope android studio 2.3.3

Comment: Try replacing `implementation` with `compile`

Comment: What gradle version do you use? Although using `compile` will still work for now, keep in mind that it is deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: This is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52297950/react-native-fbsdk-build-error-could-not-find-method-implementation/52389537#52389537 Was getting same error when adding fbsdk to a react-native app

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Replace `compile` with `implementation`.

`compile` was recently [deprecated](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ll-rkLCtyk&feature=youtu.be&t=29m18s) and replaced by `implementation` or `api`

Comment: The title says 'Could not find method implementation()' so using 'implementation' instead of 'compile' will not help (unless the error message is completely wrong)

Comment: I am already using "implementation" for an ivy module which is present in our Artifactory repository. The answer does not help

Comment: The fact with deprication is correct but does NOT lead to the errormessage displayed in the header. Look up Sunil Kumar answer: you are editing the wrong file. If confirmed please downvote this answer as it is misleading. TY

Comment: @GaVaRaVa any luck at your side?

Comment: Although this is a correct statement it doesn't help for this problem.

Answer (score 192):

Make sure you're adding these dependencies in `android/app/build.gradle`, not `android/build.gradle`.

Comment: Confirmed. This is the correct answer. The error message as described above shows when adding dependencies to the wrong build.gradle file.

Comment: @FrankKrumnow Cannot confirm because, there could be other reasons as well.

Comment: This was also my issue, after I'd spent 2 days trying to fix it. The dependencies used to live in android/build.gradle in previous versions of Cordova so this was very confusing for me.

Comment: this is the answer for me

Comment: Absolutely ridiculous that Google's own documentation doesn't mention that there are multiple build.gradle files in the project, or specify which one should be used.

Comment: I'm so glad someone decided to name so many different files with the same name ;) That's not going to be confusing.

Answer (score 59):

Make sure your Gradle version is `3.*.*` or higher before using "implementation".

Open the project level Gradle file under dependencies:

```
dependencies{
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
}
```

Open the 'gradle-wrapper.properties' file and set the `distributionUrl`:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

or latest version.

Sync the project. I Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I'm using version below 3.*.* and using 'classpath' still results to the same error. I used 'compile' instead. Thanks for this answer though about the version.

Comment: @birch3: add on top of build.gradle:  `plugins {    id 'java-library' }`

Answer (score 28):

You need to use at least **Gradle 3.4** or newer to be able to use `implementation`. It is not recommended to keep using the deprecated `compile` since this can result in slower build times. For more details see the official android developer guide:

> When your module configures an implementation dependency, it's letting Gradle know that the module does not want to leak the dependency to other modules at compile time. That is, the dependency is available to other modules only at runtime.
>   Using this dependency configuration instead of api or compile can result in significant build time improvements because it reduces the amount of projects that the build system needs to recompile. For example, if an implementation dependency changes its API, Gradle recompiles only that dependency and the modules that directly depend on it. Most app and test modules should use this configuration.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations

**Update:** `compile` will be removed by end of 2018, so make sure that you use only `implementation` now:

> Warning:Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with
>   'implementation'. It will be removed at the end of 2018

Comment: I'm already on Gradle 4.4, still having this issue suddently.

Comment: And what is your version of the gradle **plugin**? @InfiniteLoops

Comment: the plugins version is 171.4249.39. tools.build:Gradle version is 3.0.1

Comment: In Android Studio, if you create a new project from scratch: Does its gradle file use `implementation` or `compile`? @InfiniteLoops

Comment: Implementation. Weird, ain't it?

Comment: Then you should compare the gradle configs with the configs of the default project ;-)

Comment: I guess both is acceptable depends on how heavy your project is.

Comment: For me, the difference was milliseconds.  Why mess with something when it's not broken?

Comment: @user1608385 because it is deprecated and will be removed in the future

Answer (score 20):

Solved this by adding my dependancies in the app folder

Go to: **app -> Gradle Scripts -> gradle.build(Module: app) and add** the dependencies in that file and not the global build.gradle file

[image: Add your dependency in app/build.gradle]

Answer (score 19):

change  apply plugin: 'java'
to apply plugin: 'java-library'

[java-library-plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html)

Comment: Although the accepted answer appears to be the most popular, it is not the only correct answer. In my case, it was the absence of the "apply plugin: 'java-library" which resulted in the exact same exception (different object, of course). So, thanks to @xiqing-lau for adding this possible solution.

Comment: This is what helped me with Gradle 7.2

Answer (score 17):

For me I put my dependencies in the wrong spot.

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    //Don't put dependencies here.
  }
}

dependencies {
 //Put them here
}
```

Answer (score 5):

So ridiculous, but I still wanna share my experience in case of that someone falls into the situation like me.

**Please check if you changed: `compileSdkVersion` --> `implementationSdkVersion` by mistake**

Comment: "By mistake" meaning that we're *NOT* supposed to change it from compileSdk.. to implementationSdk.. right? That it is supposed to stay the compileSdkVersion?
---

Anyone reading this comment the answer is - Yes, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49755251/4132182

Comment: This is not a solution! **changing compile to implementation only applies to dependencies**.

Answer (score 4):

Your Code

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

Replace it By

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is the only suggestion that actually worked for me.  I was using compile and the project actually compiled, but then the classes on the AAR were not available at runtime inside the app.   This form of implementation solved both problems.

Answer (score 4):

I moved `implementation` to module-level build.gradle from root-level build.gradle. It solves the issue.

Comment: Yep, this solved it for me on Android Studio 4.2.2

Answer (score 3):

Replace your `implementation` with `classpath`. That should work.

Comment: Hi Nander,  I don't think my answer is similar to the accepted one. Besides, I did not work for me, which is why I posted what worked and could help other developers too.

Comment: Hi Edward, sorry, I misread. Your answer is indeed different.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50941562/2186220, use gradle plugin version 3 or higher while using 'implementation'.

Also, use the `google()` repository in `buildscript`.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    }
}
```

These changes should solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in official [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?gclid=Cj0KCQjw--GFBhDeARIsACH_kdYZ1UTjSCJ4LtZ46Zq1f_gHAcsHqvPQfbwo7kc8FM2UNGifODV_2EYaAtkpEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) you need add these :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // Gradle 4.1 and higher include support for Google's Maven repo using
        // the google() method. And you need to include this repo to download
        // Android Gradle plugin 3.0.0 or higher.
        google()
        ...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
    }
}
```

adding these remove my error. Also use implementation instead of compile.

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was that I wrote:

```
android {
    compileSdk 31
…
```

Instead of:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
```

So make sure your `build.gradle` is correct.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because I used `Implementation` instead of `implementation`.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, i was just missing `apply plugin: 'java'`

in general, make sure your gradle version is >7 for using `implementation` and that you are in the correct project

Answer (score 0):

If implementation is not defined, you are writing on a wrong file. On Unity 2019+ the correct file is `main template grandle` and not some of the others.