# Gradle Could not find implementationSdkVersion()

Tags: android, gradle

I am facing an issue with android studio 3.0.1, when I try to build the gradle project I have this message `"Could not find method implementationSDKVersion()"`

my gradle version is `4.1` and android plugin version is `3.0.1`

here is my complete build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
 implementationSdkVersion 26 //error on this line
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.anatech.evidencereporter"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
 }
 buildTypes {
     release {
         minifyEnabled false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
 }
}

dependencies {
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'
 implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
 implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'

 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.2'
 implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

any suggestions?

Comment: That should be `compileSdkVersion` not `implementationSdkVersion` change it.

Comment: @MohammedFarhan But as far as i know `compile` is deprecated

Comment: yes its deprecated to use for dependencies but not for sdk configs.

Comment: @MohammedFarhan then why does gradle specifically warn against compileSdkVersion?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is in `implementationSdkVersion` which should be `compileSdkVersion`. It happens when you are replacing automatically and blindly all the words "compile" with the word "implementation", without a "words" checkbox in the replacement options toolbar, due to gradle update. `compile` is deprecated for a future use but `compileSdkVersion` is not. Just had this issue.