# React native fbsdk build error Could not find method implementation()

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, build.gradle, facebook-login

I am using RN 0.55.4 
react-native-fbsdk 0.8.0

There is a build error

> - Where: Build file 'C:\Users\WOT\fdrrnc\node_modules\react-native-fbsdk\android\build.gradle'
>     line: 30
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-fbsdk'.
>     Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2] on object of type
>     org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

This my gradle on `android/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
```

Anyone know whats wrong?

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is still looking for this, here's what I did based on the answers from Pritish for this question and similar ones.

### Make sure you are using the compatible version of gradle

Update **android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Update **android/build.gradle** classpath

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
```

### Add maven google url

Update **android/build.gradle** (both buildscript and allprojects)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    ...
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}
```

### Check that you are using at least API 26

If you are using an older react native version prior to the changes where they updated to use API 26, check these values in your **android/app/build.gradle** file:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    ...
    targetSdkVersion 26
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your gradle version needs to be version **3.0** or higher in order to use `implementation`.

Therefore you need to upgrade it.

**build.gradle (project level)**

```
dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.x.x'
}
```

**gradle wrapper-properties**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Comment: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar
     Required by:
         project :

Comment: Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Comment: This would be the generalised error, you might need to update your `compileSdkVersion` `buildToolsVersion` as well. Not sure about that but try checking other solutions posted for that error.