# How to fix this gradle sync issue

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am getting this error
ERROR: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on project ':app'.
Open File
These are the contents of build.grade(Module : app)

```
//noinspection GradleCompatible
//noinspection ExpiredTargetSdkVersion
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "spoorthy.shopping"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

grade file(project:shopping)

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle - Error Could not find method implementation() for arguments \[com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45615474/gradle-error-could-not-find-method-implementation-for-arguments-com-android)

Comment: Your gradle version is too low, I suggest you, update ur Android Studio to a newer version

Comment: I have downloaded this app to run it on my pc.

Answer (score 0):

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.waltonbd.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/raw'] } }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Add  `testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"` in defaultConfig{} .Also add buildToolVersion

Also add google()

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: ERROR: Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container.

Comment: Upgrade the gradle .If you dont want to upgrade then use ` maven {
    url 'https://maven.google.com'
}  `

Comment: you gradle version is too low.    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

       
    }   .Update it. Go to Help ->check for update

Comment: If you solve your problem by any ans, then vote it please. Because it prove that your problem is solved. @anonymous