# Unsupported Gradle version error with Android Studio 2021.3 when creating a new Android Studio Project

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to build a new Android Studio Project as the title says and I am having this error in the Android Studio IDE :

```
Unsupported Gradle. 
The project uses Gradle version which is incompatible with Android Studio 2021.3.

Possible solution:
 - Open Gradle wrapper settings, upgrade version to 3.0 or newer and reload the project
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Thu Dec 15 13:54:44 EET 2022
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

I could not find any solution on the Internet. Please help.

I have tried changing the version to 3.0 but I don't know how to solve this problem and I need to do a project for university in Kotlin, and it does not work.

Comment: Try `syncing the project with Gradle files`

Comment: Update the Android Studio idea

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68798266/the-project-uses-gradle-2-10-which-is-incompatible-with-android-studio-2020-3)? Duplicate?

Comment: tried every solution - no result. I have seen that build.gradle project level, files often specified, has other content that any other proposed solution. could it be because of this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The project uses Gradle 2.10 which is incompatible with Android Studio 2020.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68798266/the-project-uses-gradle-2-10-which-is-incompatible-with-android-studio-2020-3)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced exactly the same problem.

In gradle-wrapper.properties change
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip
to
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.4-bin.zip

After this the problem has been solved.