# Android Studio, taking source code an creating an app

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I was trying to create an apk file from this github, https://github.com/parksjg/IndoorLTE3a.

When importing the project into android studio I got these initial issues:

"Unsupported Gradle. The project uses Gradle 2.8 which is incompatible with Android Studio 2022.3."

I then followed multiple steps from this form,  [The project uses Gradle 2.10 which is incompatible with Android Studio 2020.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68798266/the-project-uses-gradle-2-10-which-is-incompatible-with-android-studio-2020-3)

I've done everything to a tee and keep getting this issue "Gradle sync failed in 112 ms (7 minutes ago)".

Can anyone else get this working/am I doing anything wrong here?

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JO9XN.png)

Comment: Just execute `gradlew assembleRelease` on command-line without Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Install an older Android Studio version from the [downloads archive](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive), i.e. [Android Studio 3.0](https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/install/3.0.0.18/android-studio-ide-171.4408382-windows.exe). Then try again to build that repository within that version.